# Unable to load keras model through command prompt due to h5py

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, h5py

ive been trying to automate a prediction using a h5 Keras model inside a .py script and having it run through windows task scheduler. As I wrote the script on anaconda jupyter notebook and it went perfectly well I tried converting it to a .py file and running it through the Windows command line to test whether it worked or not:

`C:\Users\Jonat\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\Jonat\OneDrive\Desktop\Automated_Plant_AI_Script\Essentials\Pred_Script.py`

All the import library lines seem to be working well but I have encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\OneDrive\Desktop\Automated_Plant_AI_Script\Essentials\Pred_Script.py", line 35, in <module>
    model = load_model('CNN AI/best_model.h5')
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 580, in load_model
    raise ImportError('`load_model` requires h5py.')
ImportError: `load_model` requires h5py.
```

Solutions that I have tried:

- upgrading h5py by !pip install --upgrade h5py
- upgrading cython by !pip install --upgrade cython

Any solution is highly appreciated!

Comment: Import h5py in the same environment and see if any error comes up

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the advice. I have put import h5py in the script and turns out that h5py module was not found ```ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.```. Ive also tried installing it in conda and jupyter notebook but it still wouldnt work even if the library is properly installed.

Comment: No, the error means the hdf5 library is not installed or not in the path

Comment: H5py and hdf5 libs are  not the same thing

Comment: Hey so ive tried installing hdf5 through anaconda prompt and although it is installed successfully but i still received the same error when running the script

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Instead of running the python script through python.exe I first activate the anaconda base environment by:
`C:\Users\Jonat\anaconda3\Scripts\activate base`

then use the previous code to run everything else. I did this by creating a .bat file in which it is then scheduled to run on task scheduler.